# Combine z-indexes of nested elements of two different parents and their stacking context

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have been searching the web for a solution to my problem. All the documentation I have found so far hints that what I want to achieve is not possible. Well, is it so? Describing the problem in words:

- I have several entities where each entity has a semi-transparent overlay attached to it.
- The overlay must be rendered **behind** all the other entities including the parent entity.
- I have provided an example in the image below.

Now, the challenge part is these 2 simple rules:

- `Parent Entity A` and `Parent Entity B` must be **siblings** to each other
- `Overlay A` must be a **child of** `Parent A`, and same goes for `Overlay B`

Can we trick the stacking context to achieve this visual below?

A JS solution may be welcome as well, but know that I'm using React and I cannot do DOM manipulation directly, and the parent & sibling relation is a must.

Here's a [JS fiddle playground](https://jsfiddle.net/g8maw5nq/) to help you experiment on this. Fiddle is not the solution, it has overlays as siblings to the parent entities.

Try to nest the overlays inside their parents.

[image: example]

Comment: It's not possible with pure CSS. Think of the parent entities as "folders": folder A can not be under folder B while its content is on top of folder A. You'll have to rethink your approach.

Comment: @DanielDiekmeier  i am not restricted to pure css, is it possible in anyway?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can remove `z-index` from the entities to prevent them from creating stacking contexts, and use a negative `z-index` on the overlays to place them behind.

In the following code I define the overlays via pseudo-elements because of semantics, but with real child elements it would would work exactly the same.

```css
#entities-wrapper {
  position: relative; /* Only the wrapper (and overlays) establish */
  z-index: 0;         /* stacking contexts, entities don't.        */
}
.entity, .entity::after {
  position: absolute;
}
.entity { /* Do not use z-index here */
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 100px;
}
.entity::after { /* This is the overlay */
  content: '';
  display: block;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -150px;
  margin-top: -150px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
  border-radius: 150px;
  z-index: -1; /* Behind the entities */
}
#a {
  background: red;
  top: 150px;
  left: 200px;
}
#b {
  background: yellow;
  top: 150px;
  left: 350px;
}
```

```html
<div id="entities-wrapper">
  <div id="a" class="entity">parent entity A</div>
  <div id="b" class="entity">parent entity B</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @skyline3000 Please read [Generated Content Pseudo-elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-pseudo-4/#generated-content): "*pseudo-elements generate boxes as if they were immediate* **children** *of their originating element*". I even added a note explaining it would work for real children, see [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/g5hm8q5s/) if you are not convinced. I used pseudo-elements because of semantics.

Comment: @Oriol This works, thanks so much for your help!!! Though, in my problem, I have z-indexes on the parent-s as well, but I will try to refactor my code. I am accepting this answer, it is exactly the trick I was asking for :) !